# Resign or give notice before starting a job

Tags: contracts, employment-agreement

I have accepted a permanent manager role with a very good salary at company A and resigned from a team lead role at company B. I am supposed to start at company A on Sep 14.

However, my personal circumstances changed in the meanwhile and am in need of more money. I therefore applied for contractor roles (non-manager) which pay significantly more. Now I have been offered a contract role with company C.

Can I give notice or resign to the job at company A one day before starting?

Comment: You are not likely to get any legal issues - as this sort of thing happens often. However it is not the purpose of this website to provide legal advice. One good question would be however, "have you signed anything yet?"

Comment: Yes, I have signed a contract with company A and it mentions that both parties are required to give a week's notice to terminate the employment before end of probation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but they won't like it and you won't come away looking good. They may ask why you didn't tell them about your changed circumstances and ask for more money before accepting another offer and quitting. It's unfair that they weren't given an opportunity to modify their offer, based on your new needs, but if you didn't sign a contract then they cannot hold you to it.